# How to auto-pair to another Android device over Bluetooth without prompting for a pin?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I would like to automatically connect via Bluetooth one Android device into another Android device as soon as that device is in it's Bluetooth coverage zone.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the Bluetooth version supported on both devices.

BT2.1 or below requires a pin. You can hard code the pin (as many BT peripherals, such as headsets do).

For versions greater than BT 2.1, you can use 'just works' simple pairing, which doesn't require a pin but may prompt the user to allow it.

I don't know what the Android specific API to do these are though.

Comment: I'm using API 12 or higher. So all devices run at least Android 3.0.   What I want is to avoid the prompt which asks the user to allow that connection

Comment: The whole point of the Bluetooth security is to only allow authorised connections e.g. when security is not good enough, to let the user decide.

Comment: I think you can make unsecure RFCOMM connections in Android though!